# efficient algorithm for list edits

Tags: python, list

I have a 3D-point cloud, saved in two lists. Example with 5 points (x,y,z): (3,3,3), (1,1,1), (4,4,4), (2,2,2), (5,5,5) -> My lists looks like this:

```
z = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5] # the z values
pts = [(3,3), (1,1), (4,4), (2,2), (5,5)] # the x and y values
```

Now I want to eliminate all values where the z-value is higher than 3:

```
# what I want to receive:
z = [3, 1, 2]
pts = [(3,3), (1,1), (2,2)]
```

My algorithm is here:

```
k = -1
for i in range(len(z)):
    k += 1
    if z[k] > h:
        z.pop(k)
        pts.pop(k)
        k -= 1
```

This returns me exactly what I want - but it's very slow (for >100,000 values). 
I thought about first sorting my list via `z.sort()` and then do z = z[:index] - but when I do this for my z-list then my pts-list is still unsorted. And even if I could get both lists sorted, doesn't I also have to go through a long `loop` to find the index where my condition is `true`? 
Does anyone knows a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
z, pts = zip(*[(z, pt) for z, pt in zip(z, pts) if z <= 3])
print z, pts
```

**Output**

```
(3, 1, 2) ((3, 3), (1, 1), (2, 2))
```

Comment: thank you, I tested all 3 answers and this one is the fastest (but only a little bit faster)

Answer (score 4):

With itertools:

```
from itertools import izip, ifilter
```

zip together

```
zipped_coords = izip(z, pts)
```

filter (in post you mention `higher`, but expeted results are in fact lower, choosed first one)

```
filtered_coords = ifilter(lambda x: x[0]>=3, zipped_coords )
```

unzip

```
znew, ptsnew = map(list, izip(*filtered_coords))
```

or all-in-one oneliner

```
>>> znew, ptsnew = map(list, izip(*ifilter(lambda x: x[0]>=3, izip(z, pts))))
>>> print znew, ptsnew
[3, 4, 5] [(3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: Actually the filtering should be `x[0]<=3` according to his expected output. Also you shouldn't need the last `map`, this works `znew, ptsnew = izip(*ifilter(lambda x: x[0]>=3, izip(z, pts)))`

Comment: @JoséTomásTocino see comment in my code, OP's text contradicts with expected outout. as about map, he stated that he needs lists of coordinates, not tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are removing elements from the list as you iterate it is a O(N^2) algorithm. You can use a simple list comprehension along with `zip` to do this in linear time.

```
z = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5] # the z values
pts = [(3,3), (1,1), (4,4), (2,2), (5,5)] # the x and y values

merged = zip(z, pts)    
filtered = [x for x in merged if x[0] <= 3]
z, pts = zip(*filtered)
```